# Open graph og:see_also parameter using method

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

> og:see_also   Array  An array of URLs of related resources

How to use this, I mean how should the array look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

og:see_also  - Used to supply an additional link that shows related content to the object.

The Markup will look like this,

```
<meta property="og:see_also" content="http://www.website.com"/>
```

If a tag can have multiple values, just put multiple versions of the same  tag on your page. The first tag (from top to bottom) is given preference during conflicts.

```
<meta property="og:see_also" content="http://example.com/page1" />
<meta property="og:see_also" content="http://example.com/page2" />
```

Checkout this [Open Graph Portal](http://ogp.me/#array)